# the neccessary I don't understand about install python2.7

Tags: python

I found the answers from [Building Python and more on missing modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171210/building-python-and-more-on-missing-modules).

Also the problem I meet is that. But something I didn't understand eg to how to install these 
modules.

```
    Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _tkinter           bsddb185        
dbm                gdbm               sunaudiodev     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

I can install these, but I have something can't understand, the older python which Ubuntu take,Is there something the new Python can't find, or something else.If I end the install ,How to make the system to use the version I installed?

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/python /usr/bin/python
```

On my pc,It didn't work.So where my fault?
If I install another version of Python, which version to choose before I use? And is there problem about using else soft?

Comment: Unless you *have* to build TKInter GUI code, I would not worry about this *at all*.

Comment: The rest of the list of modules are things your platform doesn't support or are obsolete and have been deprecated.

Comment: Can I use sudo apt-get install python-tk?But the else represent what?

Comment: `python-tk` is built to go with the `python` package for your Debian or Ubuntu installation, *not* for your own Python build. Install `tk-dev` instead.

Comment: The others are `dbm` variations. You are not likely to ever need those. See `http://docs.python.org/2/library/anydbm.html` for an overview of what Python supports. `sunaudiodev` is for SUN-system audio devices. You don't have one.

Comment: I make is successfully,and I have another question.If I want to use Python3.3, I ln -s /usr/local/python3/python /usr/bin/python, It can work or not?

Comment: That can break other Python scripts that expect Python 2. I'd not link this into `/usr/bin` *at all*; use `/usr/local/bin` instead.

Comment: I knew.Now I use a soft,but It it reply me that { ImportError: No module named dbus },what is dbus? I use the command { ImportError: No module named dbus },but when I retry ,it also there.

Comment: `dbus` is an external library to integrate with the Gnome dbus system. It does not come with Python itselsf.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about most of those modules.

The `tkinter` module requires Tcl/Tk with headers, on a Debian-based system installing `tk-dev` is enough to satisfy the requirements.

The `sunaudiodev` module requires you to have a Sun audio device. You don't have one, trust me.

The `db` modules are legacy modules. You *could* install `libdb4.8-dev` to get some of these to compile, but I would not worry about these. The [`anydbm` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/anydbm.html) will switch between available modules as needed, but almost all modern code has long since abandoned using DBM-like storage in favor of sqlite3.