# How can I add the sqlite3 module to Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, pip

Can someone tell me how to install the sqlite3 module alongside the most recent version of Python?
I am using a Macbook, and on the command line, I tried:

```
pip install sqlite
```

but an error pops up.

Comment: If your python is built from source manually , and meet this error, you should install sqlite-devel package first, then rebuild python, as @falsetru said, the package name  will be vary depending on the Operating system.

Comment: For everone trying to build python from source and running into this error: This really good answer adresses the bulild process and the dependencys you need. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6171511/6273503

Answer (score 339, accepted):

You don't need to install [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module. It is included in the standard library (since Python 2.5).

Comment: I actually have a python 2.5.4 that does not included sqlite3 :(

Comment: @user722915, According to [What's New in Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/2.7/whatsnew/2.5.html#the-sqlite3-package), The pysqlite module (http://www.pysqlite.org), a wrapper for the SQLite embedded database, has been added to the standard library under the package name sqlite3.

Comment: if your python3 is built from source manually , and meet this error,  you should install sqlite-devel package first, then rebuild python3.

Comment: @ngn999, You'd better comment to the question to let OP know it. Because this was answered very long time, and it is not notified to OP if you comment to the answer.

Comment: @ngn999, BTW, the package name will be vary depending on the Operating system. For example, in Ubuntu, it's `libsqlite3-dev`.

Comment: LITERALLY LIFED MY SAVE!

Comment: @ngn999 your comment should be the answer for python3 users. It solved my problem.

Comment: Python3 official module page https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html
CPython 3.12 source code for sqlite3 https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.12/Lib/sqlite3/

Answer (score 74):

For Python version 3:

```
pip install pysqlite3
```

Comment: pysqlite3 is just a wrapper.  It won't work if you don't actually have the SQLite libraries in your system (or the devel package if you built Python from sources).

Comment: I tried this and it installed, but I still couldn't use it. Any ideas? Here's what it says when I run the command:   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pysqlite3, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pysqlite3
  Running setup.py install for pysqlite3 ... done
Successfully installed pysqlite3

Answer (score 42):

I have python 2.7.3 and this solved my problem:

```
pip install pysqlite
```

Comment: Consider that this is not applicable to Python 3.

Answer (score 28):

Normally, it is included. However, as @ngn999 said, if your python has been built from source manually, you'll have to add it.

Here is an example of a script that will setup an **encapsulated version (virtual environment) of Python3** in your user directory with an **encapsulated version of sqlite3**.

```
INSTALL_BASE_PATH="$HOME/local"
cd ~
mkdir build
cd build
[ -f Python-3.6.2.tgz ] || wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.2/Python-3.6.2.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-3.6.2.tgz

[ -f sqlite-autoconf-3240000.tar.gz ] || wget https://www.sqlite.org/2018/sqlite-autoconf-3240000.tar.gz
tar -zxvf sqlite-autoconf-3240000.tar.gz

cd sqlite-autoconf-3240000
./configure --prefix=${INSTALL_BASE_PATH}
make
make install

cd ../Python-3.6.2
LD_RUN_PATH=${INSTALL_BASE_PATH}/lib configure
LDFLAGS="-L ${INSTALL_BASE_PATH}/lib"
CPPFLAGS="-I ${INSTALL_BASE_PATH}/include"
LD_RUN_PATH=${INSTALL_BASE_PATH}/lib make
./configure --prefix=${INSTALL_BASE_PATH}
make
make install

cd ~
LINE_TO_ADD="export PATH=${INSTALL_BASE_PATH}/bin:\$PATH"
if grep -q -v "${LINE_TO_ADD}" $HOME/.bash_profile; then echo "${LINE_TO_ADD}" >> $HOME/.bash_profile; fi
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

Why do this? You might want a modular python environment that you can completely destroy and rebuild without affecting your managed package installation. This would give you an independent development environment. In this case, the solution is to install sqlite3 modularly too.

Comment: Can also happen if you use pyenv to manage your Python versions, but you didn't have all the system packages installed when the Python interpreter was installed.

Comment: I had a requirement where I didn't want to disturb the existing python setup. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks !!

Answer (score 5):

if you have error in Sqlite built in python you can use Conda to solve this conflict

```
conda install sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows + Conda users: you have to download the sqlite3 dll, uncompress and copy the file into the DLL dir in Conda installion path

[Check this answer for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642416/1556106)

Answer (score -2):

sqlite3 automatically comes with python. You can upgrade python version if you need latest version of sqlite3 or follow steps from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: It depends very much how you install python and on which platform if sqlite3 if included