# install sqlite3 on windows using pip

Tags: python, sqlite

How to install `sqlite` in Python?

I tried `pip install pysqlite3` and and it gives me an error

```
your texterror: subprocess-exited-with-error

 × Building wheel for pysqlite3 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pysqlite3
      copying pysqlite3\dbapi2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pysqlite3
      copying pysqlite3\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pysqlite3
      running build_ext
      Builds a C extension linking against libsqlite3 library
      building 'pysqlite3._sqlite3' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysqlite3
Failed to build pysqlite3
ERROR: Could not build wheels for p
ysqlite3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: SQLite support is part of the Python standard library, though there are third party libs for it you most likely won't need to install them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19530987/10787867

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add the sqlite3 module to Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530974/how-can-i-add-the-sqlite3-module-to-python)

Answer (score 0):

this is because SQLite is wrong or not installed in the path if you use Windows.
You can check if SQLite is working on your PC through Python by running a small program that attempts to open or create an SQLite database.

```html
import sqlite3

try:
    # Attempts to create a connection to an in-memory SQLite database.
    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    print("SQLite is running on your system.")
    conn.close()
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
    print("SQLite is not working correctly on your system.")
```