# Guide to compile Python3.10 with sqlite if it didn't come with it?

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, pip

I've installed Python version 3.10 for a project by:

```
me@mydevice:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
me@mydevice:~$ sudo apt update
me@mydevice:~$ sudo apt install python3.10
```

Afterwards I created a virtual environment in which I installed jupyter. I am now unable to run it since jupyter complains it can't find sqlite3.

**EDIT** More specifically, the exception thrown is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project_path/venv/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.app import main
  File "/home/project_path/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/app.py", line 17, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.serverapp import flags
  File "/home/project_path/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/serverapp.py", line 95, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.gateway.managers import (
  File "/home/project_path/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/gateway/managers.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/home/project_path/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3  # type:ignore[no-redef]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

I checked the file `/home/project_path/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py` and the import it's trying to do is actually:

```
try:
    import sqlite3
except ImportError:
    # fallback on pysqlite2 if Python was build without sqlite
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3  # type:ignore[no-redef]
```

So the bottom line is I don't have sqlite3.
**ENDEDIT**

**EDIT2** After removing the `try except` in the file and just leaving `import sqlite3`, I end up with the following trace:

```
 File "/home/project_path/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_trace_v2
```

**ENDEDIT2**

`pip install pysqlite`,  `pip install sqlite3` and `pip install sqlite2` don't find matching distributions. Neither does `pip install --upgrade sqlite3` etc.

I've read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530974/how-can-i-add-the-sqlite3-module-to-python) and it seems like it should come automatically with python, but **if** it doesn't, then one should compile python with it somehow.

Could somebody give some steps of how to compile python with it or point to a guide (google didn't help)? I am not familiar with compiling python from scratch to include whatever packages you want, where you would get them from and what to do with them once you get them etc. I have only installed it before in the way I mentioned above.

Comment: "*I am now unable to run it since jupyter complains it can't find sqlite3.*" Can you share the exact text of the stack trace or error message which you're referring to here? `sqlite3` is a core component of Python, and it would be very strange if you installed Python from `deadsnakes/ppa` and it was not included in that build.

Comment: @esqew I added the exact text of the stack trace, mentioned it as an EDIT.

Comment: `if it doesn't` don't assume it's not included. It's far more likely that you forgot to import it or have a typo

Comment: The error complains about `'pysqlite2'` not sqlite3. Remove the `try` block and post what happens if you use `import sqlite3`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't see where I could have forgotten to import it, since all I'm trying to do is run a jupyter notebook command.

Comment: We can't guess what's going on on your machine. We don't even have the error message right now. Post the actual error thrown when you use just  `import sqlite3`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right, it helps to see that error. I've just edited.

Comment: I was able to spin up an Ubuntu VM in Azure and following the steps above to install `python3.10` from `deadsnakes/ppa` and attempting to `import sqlite3` does not result in any sort of exception. I have to imagine this is something to do with either the `venv` you've set up or the instance/configuration of Jupyter in your environment. How exactly did you install Jupyter and set up the `venv`?

Comment: @esqew Your answer solved it. I had installed jupyter with `pip install jupyter`, not with `apt install python3-notebook`.